# How can I solve this XAML Binding error?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

First some background, which can be condensed into editing a property VatCode of VatCodeViewModel.

I have a StockItem with two particular properties in the ViewModel:

```
public class StockItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private VatCodeViewModel _vatCode;

    public VatCodeViewModel VatCode
    {
        get { return _vatCode; }
        set
        {
            if (_vatCode != value)
            {
                _vatCode = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("VatCode");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The VatCode property accepts a VatCodeViewModel type.

To manage the editing experience, I have a ViewModel called EditStockItemViewModel. This has meta-data such as IsDirty, IsNew, etc., but has the Item property set to the item being edited - in this case an instance of StockItemViewModel. The Item property is in the base class (of TViewModel == StockItemViewModel) ...

```
public class UnMappedEditableViewModelBase<TViewModel> : ViewModelBase
{
    private TViewModel _item;

    public TViewModel Item
    {
        get { return _item; }
        set
        {
            if (_item != value)
            {
                _item = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the implementation class (EditStockItemViewModel, which has Item of StockItemViewModel) ...

```
public class EditStockItemViewModel : UnMappedEditableViewModelBase<StockItemViewModel>
{
        private ObservableCollection<VatCodeViewModel> _vatCodes=new ObservableCollection<VatCodeViewModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<VatCodeViewModel> VatCodes
    {
        get { return _vatCodes; }
        set
        {
            if (_vatCodes != value)
            {
                _vatCodes = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("VatCodes");
            }
        }
    }


public EditStockItemViewModel()
        :base()
{
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
        }
        else
        {
                                RefreshVatCodesList(null); // refreshes VatCodes property


            Save = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                                                // save functionality snipped

                }, () =>
            {
                bool canExecute =                        Item.VatCode!=null; // this is ALWAYS null - binding failing
                return canExecute;
            });         
        }
    }


}
```

*Therefore the ViewModel.Item property is always the item being edited.*

A fragment of my view ...

```
    <TextBlock Text="VAT Code:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource ComboHeaderTextBlock}" />
    <telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource RadComboBox}" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                ItemsSource="{Binding VatCodes}" SelectedValuePath="Item.VatCode" 
                ClearSelectionButtonVisibility="Collapsed"
                CanAutocompleteSelectItems="True"
                CanKeyboardNavigationSelectItems="True"
                IsEditable="False"
                OpenDropDownOnFocus="False"
                IsFilteringEnabled="False"
                EmptyText="Select ...">
        <telerik:RadComboBox.SelectedValue>
            <Binding Path="Item.VatCode" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" >
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <DataErrorValidationRule />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </telerik:RadComboBox.SelectedValue>
        <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlock}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource DimTextBlock}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActiveRate.Rate}" Margin="5 5 0 5" />
                    <TextBlock Text="%" Margin="0 5 5 5"  />
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

So at the end of all this, I have:

VatCode that binds to [ViewModel].Item.VatCode and uses [ViewModel].VatCodes as source.

The list is populated and appears fine. I know that the ViewModel is binding correctly.

The problem is the VatCode is NOT binding to the Item.VatCode property. So when I get to the Save method, the Item.VatCode property is null (ie. not working).

I am getting the following binding error which appears to be related:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Item' value (type
>   'String') from '' (type 'VatCodeViewModel').
>   BindingExpression:Path=Item.VatCode; DataItem='VatCodeViewModel'
>   (HashCode=27875274); target element is 'RadComboBox' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
>   TargetParameterCountException:'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException:
>   Parameter count mismatch.

Clearly the error indicates my binding expression Item.VatCode is suspect, but I'm not sure how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I was misled by the example provided in the documentation. I should not have used the path `SelectedValuePath`. So my new code is:

```
 <TextBlock Text="VAT Code:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource ComboHeaderTextBlock}" />
        <telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource RadComboBox}" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding VatCodes}"  
                    ClearSelectionButtonVisibility="Collapsed"
                    CanAutocompleteSelectItems="True"
                    CanKeyboardNavigationSelectItems="True"
                    IsEditable="False"
                    OpenDropDownOnFocus="False"
                    IsFilteringEnabled="False"
                    EmptyText="Select ...">
            <telerik:RadComboBox.SelectedValue>
                <Binding Path="Item.VatCode" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <DataErrorValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </telerik:RadComboBox.SelectedValue>
            <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlock}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource DimTextBlock}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActiveRate.Rate}" Margin="5 5 0 5" />
                        <TextBlock Text="%" Margin="0 5 5 5"  />
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line of your combo box markup:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding VatCodes}" SelectedValuePath="Item.VatCode"
```

This says to pull the items for the combo box from *VatCodes* (type *VatCodeViewModel*), and for the combo box value take a property of *VatCodeViewModel* called *Item.VatCode*.  It's hard to say without seeing the definition of *VatCodeViewModel*, but I suspect that property doesn't exist.

Here's what I think you're meaning to do.  Make *SelectedValuePath* a property of *VatCodeViewModel* (let's say *VatCode*), and then bind the selection to *Item.VatCode*.  You can do it like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding VatCodes}" SelectedValuePath="VatCode" SelectedValue="{Binding Item.VatCode}"
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry, that doesn't work. I am using the SelectedValue expression you suggest already in the break-out code for <telerik:RadComboBox.SelectedValue>. Changing the SelectedValuePath to VatCode doesn't work, either. Wish I could vote you up for helping.